# JS function startsWith fails to give correct output.What is code smell in my code?

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, compare, string-comparison

I have written this code to sort a list with respect to user input, but if user have added a input which contains space between the input then the following code fails to get the output, what changes do I need to make to get correct output? I dont want to remove space between characters.
For ex: User input is 'Man santra' then it should sort a list wrt "Man"

```
 var users = [{
    name: 'Devgad Mango'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mantra santra'
  },
  {
    name: 'Prag Mango'
  },
  {
    name: 'Pirate aam Mango'
  }, {
    name: 'Mango raw'
  },
];

function search(input) {
  const matches = [];
  const remeinder = [];
  users.forEach(user => {
    user.name.startsWith(input) ?
      matches.push(user) :
      remeinder.push(user);
  });
  console.log(matches, remeinder)

  // now we sort the matches

  matches.sort((a, b) => {
    const aa = a.name.toLowerCase();
    const bb = b.name.toLowerCase();
    if (aa < bb) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (aa > bb) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });

  console.log(matches);
  // now we want to push the remeinders to the end of the sorted array.


  matches.push(...remeinder);

  console.log(matches);
  console.log(input);
}
const str = "*-*+&^%$#@!/\Man santra*";
var output = (str.replace(/[\/\\#@^!,+()&$~%.'":;*?`<>{}-]/g, ""));


search(output);
```

Comment: may be because of `user.name.startsWith(input)`, try `user.name.includes(input)`

Comment: Did you mean `input.includes(user.name)` or `input.startsWith(user.name)` instead of `user.name.startsWith(input)`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use user.name.includes() to check if the name exists in the variable or not. Then you don't have to remove the spaces. You just have to pass the input in the search function and it will return the matches that contain that word.

```js
var users = [{
    name: 'Devgad Mango'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mantra santra'
  },
  {
    name: 'Prag Mango'
  },
  {
    name: 'Pirate aam Mango'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mango raw'
  },
];

function search(input) {
  const matches = [];
  const remeinder = [];
  users.forEach(user => {
    user.name.includes(input) ?
      matches.push(user) :
      remeinder.push(user);
  });
  
  // now we sort the matches
  matches.sort((a, b) => {
    const aa = a.name.toLowerCase();
    const bb = b.name.toLowerCase();
    if (aa < bb) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (aa > bb) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });

  console.log(matches);
  // now we want to push the remeinders to the end of the sorted array.
  matches.push(...remeinder);
  console.log(matches);
}
const str = "Mango";
search(str);
```

Comment: Here my first requirement is to sort a result wrt to searched value. I.e when you search "Mango" then it should sort a result with mango, thats the reason I used startswith() function

Comment: If you see the code the sort function is working on the name, not on the search value. If you can see the output actually it is in the sorted order alphabetically. If you want to sort it based on the input, can you please explain or give an example of how the output will look like?